# Opening winforms in the same screen

Tags: vb.net

I have an application with multiple win forms. I have noticed is that if the user has multiple screen displays and changes the application to one screen, the other forms that are called by other buttons, will open in the main display and not where my main application or form is.

How can I change this?

Comment: Try checking `Screen` class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx) and look at `PrimaryScreen` property. So if it is Primary screen make it visible. Is this what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`Form.CenterToParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.centertoparent.aspx) Method on your Forms, they will then open up centered on your the creating Form, Or you can use the Screen Class to get the Bounds of the Display that your Main application is running on, then pass it to your created forms.

**Edit:**

On second thought assigning the `Owner` might just be enough, I don't have a dual monitor computer booted up at this time to test though

```
Dim frm As Form1 = New Form1()
frm.Owner = Me
frm.CenterToParent()
frm.Show()
```

---

**Edit**

Just had a chance to check it out. It was as I thought assigning the `Owner` to the new `Form` or using the [`Form.Show(IWin32Window)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd.aspx) will open the new `Form` on the same screen as the originating `Form`.

`frm.Show(Me)`

---

Looks like the `CenterToParent` property is protected now. 
According to the MSDN link

> Do not call the CenterToParent method directly from your code. Instead, set the StartPosition property to CenterParent.
>   If the form or dialog is top-level, then CenterToParent centers the form with respect to the screen or desktop

Comment: Note: just setting Owner was not sufficient in my tests.  And `Form.CenterToParent()` is protected so you cannot just call it directly.

Comment: Looks like they changed it in the newer frameworks. According to the link I have in my answer it says to use Form.SetPosition with CenterParent enumeration.

Comment: However, bizarrely, using only `frm.Show(Me)` *did* work for me.  Weird.

Comment: None of the options are working for me, after moving the owner from one screen to another. The new form will popup on the screen where the owner was created.

Comment: This way worked for me though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411839/create-new-form-on-same-screen-position/32411919