# Create new form on same screen position

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, winforms, location

I want to create a new form on the same location. When I call this code a new form opens but on a different screen position.

```
private void BtnAddForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Form2 form2 = new Form2();
     form2.Tag = this;
     form2.Location = this.Location;
     form2.Show(this);
     Hide();
}
```

I used `this.Location` to get the location from my first form but this has no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `StartPosition` property to `Manual` for this to work.

```
private void BtnAddForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Tag = this;
    form2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;         
    form2.Location = this.Location;
    form2.Show(this);
    Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is by using the the `StartPosition` property of the form. This property should be set before the form is shown. You can set this property before you call the Show or ShowDialog method or in your form's constructor.

For example: 
`form2.StartPosition  = FormStartPosition.CenterParent`

Answer (score 1):

Use this. Hope helps

```
    private void BtnAddForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show(this);
        form2.Tag = this;
        form2.Location = this.Location;
        Hide();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but makes the page jump so it doesn't look very smooth

Comment: ok I just fixed your code. @user2946329 's answer works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `form2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;`, You should also use `form2.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();` to close parent form after hide it Try this:

```
Hide();
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Tag = this;
form2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
form2.Location = this.Location;
form2.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
form2.Show();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 NewForm = new Form1();
    NewForm.Show();
    NewForm.Location = this.Location;
    this.Dispose(false);
}
```

> This is a pretty simple one.

Comment: Your answer does not provide any new meaningful information when compared to the accepted answer.